# Windows 7 shuts down automatically after 3-5 minutes unless I wait 3-5 minutes before login

Tags: windows-7, windows, shutdown

I've tried to:

- Disable all services/startup programs in msconfig (including microsoft ones)
- Check the disk for errors
- Starting up in safe mode (works just fine)
- Event Viewer (no description of the shutdown just error id 6008)
- Doing a System Restore causes the computer to shutdown failing to complete the restore.restauro

I am out of option here but the last thing I want to do is to reset the windows.

Comment: So when you login it shuts down after 3-5 minutes, but if you wait that long to login, it's fine?

Comment: @CustomX Pretty much yes, I can't pinpoint what's causing it

Comment: Can you check event log, if it logs something when you logon without waiting? Try to compare it with event log when you wait before logon.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/326564/event-id-6008-is-unexpectedly-logged-to-the-system-event-log-after-you may help you out

Comment: Failing that, there is http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2960465/event-6008-unexpected-shutdowns.html

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following steps:

1.Go to start menu then control panel.
2.click on system.
3.Go to advance system settings.
4.select startup and recovery and click on setting then uncheck the check box near automatically restart.
5. click OK in startup and recovery window and in the System Properties window.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem but not the same one.
I found that my video drivers were the cause. After deleting the drivers I didn't need (3D) it solved my problem.
Hope this helps.